# Solubility of gases in water in comparison to their liquefiability

Tags: physical-chemistry, solubility, solutions

My textbook of physical chemistry says

> ...The following factors affect the solubilities of gases in liquids:
>
> **(i) Nature of the gas and solvent:** Generally, the gases which
> can be easily liquefied are more soluble in common solvents. For example, $CO_2$ is more soluble in water than oxygen or hydrogen. The gases which react with the solvent posses higher solubility. For example, $HCl$ and $NH_3$ are highly soluble in water.
>
> Oxygen, nitrogen and carbon dioxide are much more soluble
> in ethyl alcohol than in water at the same temperature and
> pressure.
>
> **(ii) Temperature:** The solubility of most of the gases in
> liquids decreases with increase...

*Why is it so that the gases which can be easily liquefied are more soluble?*

I mean, more liquefiable gases would have a stronger attractive forces amongst the molecule. This would mean that it would become increasingly tougher to dissolve them as their ability to be liquified increase. Then why the opposite is true?

---

Edit

I found a similar question on Chemistry.SE here asking [Why does physisorption (physical adsorption) increase with ease of liquefaction?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68366/why-does-physisorption-physical-adsorption-increase-with-ease-of-liquefaction#:%7E:text=You%20are%20correct%20to%20say,(van%20der%20Waals%20forces).&text=So%20if%20the%20gas%20molecules,der%20Waals%20forces%20of%20attraction.). I know the above question (and answers) are aimed at adsorption and mine is about solubility, but I think there must be an explanation like that for the aforementioned one.

Comment: Make some hand-waving about the strength of the intermolecular interactions.

Comment: Because it's a crappy textbook, or you haven't been reading it thoroughly? ;)

Comment: @Karl - I feel like you would be happy to know that the textbook is among the standard ones used by students (atleast in my country)

Comment: @SteelCubes If this is one of the *10 in One Study Package for CBSE Chemistry Class* books, they I have to agree with Karl—the quality of that stuff is way below average from I can see on [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=25PuDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). If you *must* use this sort of literature, then so be it, but I would recommend to take a glimpse of the [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry).

Comment: @andselisk - The text quoted is from _PHYSICAL CHEMISTRY FOR COMPETITIONS by Dr. O.P. Tondon (G.R.B. Publication)_

Comment: @anselisk - Honestly, even I'd have to agree that these _10 in One Study Package for CBSE Chemistry Class_ type of books count quite too low in quality

Comment: @SteelCubes Isn't it T**a**ndon? Anyway, *10 in One Study Package…* is where I found the exact quotation of yours. I don't know who copied from whom, but still a recommendation to get a better textbook holds true.

Comment: @ andselisk - Apologies, yes it is Tandon indeed. Moreover, I'll surely consider your suggestion. But the thing is, I have encountered this statement and its similar variants at multiple occasions. And the above textbook is just one of them. Could you please have a look at this question [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-in/question/a-gas-with-higher-critical-temperature-is-adsorbed-more-than-a-gas-with-lower-critical/)

Comment: Whenever someone asks here about something that is seemingly sloppily explained in a textbook, I bet myself one buck on the book having something to do with the JEE, and charity isn't doing very well on that. ;) Your country's educational systems is based on textbooks written by undereducated morons, to make sure you never get better than them. Sorry.